# Why does starting point of graph differ?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, universe

[image]

[image]

Why open universe, flat universe, closed universe have a different starting point?
I know they have different age.

I want the solution using mathematical method

Answer (score 1):

The Friedmann equation describing the evolution of the universe can be written (in units where $\hbar=c=G=1$) as
$$H^2+\frac{k}{a^2}=\frac{1}{3M_{\mathrm{pl}}^2}\rho,$$ where $H=\frac{\dot{a}}{a}$, $a$ is the scale factor, $k$ is 1,-1, or 0, depending on the curvature, and $M_{\mathrm{pl}}$ is the planck mass. $\rho$ is the energy density of a combination of different components of the universe, usually given to be radiation (index $r$), matter ($m$) and dark energy/cosmological constant ($\Lambda$).
The continuity equation makes it possible to solve, how the energy density of these different components changes with $a$, the scale factor, for example $\rho_r=\rho_{r,0}\left(\frac{a}{a_0}\right)^{-4}$, where $0$ denotes that we look at the quantities today.

Normalising the densities with the so called critical density $\rho_{\mathrm{crit}}\equiv 3M_{\mathrm{pl}}^2 H^2$ by introducing $\Omega_{i,0}=\frac{\rho_{i,0}}{\rho_{\mathrm{crit},0}}$, and the curvature parameter $\Omega_{k}\equiv\frac{k}{a(t)^2H^2(t)}$, makes it possible to rewrite the first equation as
$$H^2(t)=H_0^2\left(\Omega_{r,0}a^{-4}+\Omega_{m,0}a^{-3}+\Omega_{k,0}a^{-2}+\Omega_{\Lambda}\right)$$
We also have set $a_0=1$, meaning the scale factor is normalised to 1 today. Now you can see how the different components behave differently as $a$ evolves. We can now rewrite $H=\frac{\dot{a}}{a}=\frac{da}{dt}\frac{1}{a}$, and solve this differential equation for $t$ by separation of variables. The physicist method is to bring $da$ and all terms with $a$'s to one side and all terms with $dt$ to the other and then to integrate both, the result is
$$t_0=H_0^{-1}\int_0^1\frac{da}{\sqrt{\Omega_{r,0}a^{-2}+\Omega_{m,0}a^{-1}+\Omega_{\Lambda}a^{2}+\Omega_{k,0}}}.$$
We integrate from 0 to 1, because we normalised the scale factor to 1 today, and assume it was 0 "at the big bang". You can clearly see that this expression will give you different results for different values of $\Omega$. This will give different ages of the universe and hence different starting points of the graph you showed depending on the different content distribution.

Comment: thanks. but i wonder why starting points of the first graph coincide. i know that  The Friedmann equation also describe the first graph.

Comment: @빛나는밤, I would not trust that plot in this regards.

Comment: The different origins of the curves are that way because the x value represents the time, and the arbitrary assumption is made that t=0 is now. This is a different arbitrary choice from a more common choice that t=0 represents the start of the  universe, which is a singularity in the general relativity model.

Comment: But if you set t=0 to the start of the standard cosmological universe, then t_now should be different depending on the energy content of the universe. This is why the first plot is misleading.

Comment: thanks i think i understand